# LUA string, remove all characters after last occurrence of white space

Tags: string, lua

Anyone knows or have idea how to remove all characters after last occurrence of white space in **LUA**, for example

**foo = "This is some string"**

to get

**bar = "This is some"**

Comment: `boo=string.match(foo, "^(.*) ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
bar = foo:gsub("(.*)%s.*$","%1")
```

The pattern greedily captures everything until a whitespace is seen and discards the rest of the string. The key point here is *greedily*, which has the effect of finding the *last* whitespace.